# Customizing My Sites portlet in Liferay

Tags: liferay

I want to customize My Sites portlet (which is out of box portlet) in liferay using ext. How do I do this? How do I get the source code for the my sites portlet?

Comment: It's enough to build an hook plugin to customize "my sites". You can download the portal source code from official distro in liferay.com to have the code.

Comment: Thanks Daniele, I have to customize the "mysitesPortlet".java of "my sites" because I want to have my own functionality when a user requests for a site membership. I'm assuming for this i need an ext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the files structure for **My Sites** portlet in portal source:

**Views:**

```
\portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\my_sites\  
    - view.jsp
    - site_action.jsp
```

**Action:**

```
\portal-impl\src\com\liferay\portlet\myplaces\action\ViewAction.java
```

The initial view is being rendered from `view.jsp` with the help of `group_search.jsp` (Search field) and `site_action.jsp` (Actions button).
To ensure action file, open `\portal-web\docroot\WEB-INF\struts-config.xml`, copy any of the **struts_action** value set as parameter for the render / action URLs appearing on the `view.jsp` (lets say `/my_sites/view` and `/sites_admin/page`), you will find following mappings in `struts-config.xml`

**/my_sites/view**

```
<action path="/my_sites/view" type="com.liferay.portlet.myplaces.action.ViewAction">
    <forward name="portlet.my_sites.view" path="portlet.my_sites.view" />
</action>
```

**/sites_admin/page**

```
<action path="/sites_admin/page" type="com.liferay.portlet.myplaces.action.ViewAction" />
```

If you aren't familiar with extension environment, you can refer [Setup Guide](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Setting+up+the+Extension+Environment) and [Development Guide](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Development+in+the+ext+environment)

Now, to extend these files, you should have following structure in your ext:

**Views:**

```
\ext\testExt\docroot\WEB-INF\ext-web\docroot\html\portlet\my_sites\
    - view.jsp
    - site_action.jsp
```

**Action:**

```
\ext\testExt\docroot\WEB-INF\ext-impl\src\com\liferay\portlet\myplaces\action\ViewAction.java
```

> **Note:** testExt is the name of your extension folder.

I hope, this is the sufficient information to start with and will help you.

I would like to enlighten on more thing, i.e.

> As suggested by **Daniele Baggio**, if your requirement can be
>   fulfilled with changes in struts action and JSPs, you should go with the HOOK implementation.

Comment: "for extensive amount of the changes throughout the portal code, the extension environment is the best option" - NO. First, Extension Environment doesn't exist for ~5 years now. Second, ext-plugins are the most intrusive and potentially least maintainable way to modify Liferay's behaviour. ANY changes that CAN be done in a hook SHOULD be made in a hook. Keep your ext-plugins as small as possible, in the interest of maintainability. No matter how "extensive" the changes are. USE A HOOK for modifying just a Struts action and some jsps! Don't even consider an ext-plugin as first option

Comment: You mean ext-portlets to refer ext-plugins are the most intrusive and potentially least maintainable way to modify Liferay's behaviour.